# How to use Strings in CONCAT

Tags: db2

I'm using PHP PDO to query from DB2.

The following works.

```
$sql = "SELECT  COL1,
                CONCAT(COL2,COL3) cat
                FROM TABLE 
                WHERE COL4 = $param";

$statement = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

But...I want to insert a `'-'` in between COL2 & COL3 in the `CONCAT`

But..doing

```
$sql = "SELECT      COL1,
                    CONCAT(COL2,'-',COL3) cat
                    FROM TABLE 
                    WHERE COL4 = $param";
    
    $statement = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
```

Does not work. I even tried escaping the quotes for `'-'`. Any idea how to insert a String into the CONCAT params?

Comment: You say DB2, but tag <mysql>. Which one are you using?

Comment: and also when you say doesn't work , what does it mean? do you get an error message? paste the error message as well

Comment: And what does "does not work" actually mean? What happens?

Comment: In DB2 `CONCAT()` can only take two arguments, in MySQL any number.

Comment: Why do you use `prepare()` if you don't parameterize your query? You are still currently vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Use `||` operator to concat more than 2 strings.

Comment: Why you're adding PHP code to your SQL problem? Always localize the problem area, removing all unrelated details.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton What do you mean? How is this vulnerable to injection?

Comment: @user2402616 Sorry, it _could_ be vulnerable depending on how `$param` is set (I'm assuming it _is_ vulnerable because I can't see how you set `$param`). But using `prepare()` without parameterizing the query is completely useless and doesn't protect you at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select col1, col2 || '-' || col3 as cat from table where col4 = $param
```